# How to implement multiple methods in abstract class? European

Tags: java

Im new to java and struggle to understand abstract classes and the inheritance of methods:
Here is what I have tried to set up in order to get a better grasp of abstract classes. I have a abstract class Citizen which should help to convert weight among citizens:

```
    public abstract class Citizen{

        public double weight;
        /**
         * Constructor of the abstract class
         */
        public Citizen(double weight) {
            this.weight = weight;
        }

        public abstract double doubleValue();
    }
```

I have some individuals who extend Citizen - John:

```
    public class American extends Citizen{

        public American(int weight) {
            super(weight);
        }
        @Override
        public double doubleValue() {
            return weight;
        }

    }
```

Peter:

```
    public class European extends Citizen {

      public European(int weight) {
          super(weight);
      }
      @Override
      public double doubleValue() {
          return weight;
      }

    }
```

Françoise:

```
    public class European extends Citizen {

      public European(int weight) {
          super(weight);
      }
      @Override
      public double doubleValue() {
          return weight;
      }

    }
```

And here I try to put them together:

```
    import java.util.*;

    public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args){

            European.setWeight(2,20462); # should convert Françoise to pound
            European.setWeight(2,20462); # should convert Peter to pound

            List<Citizen> weightiness = new ArrayList<Citizen>();
            weightiness.add(new European(100)); # Converted to pound
            weightiness.add(new European(95)); # Converted to pound
            weightiness.add(new American(220));

            for (int i = 0; i < weightiness.size(); i++){
                System.out.println(weightiness.get(i).doubleValue());
            }

        }
    }
```

Since European are from Europe they are measured in kilogram and Americans are measured in pounds. 
I would like to compute the overall weightiness of all of them in pounds and therefore have to convert European by setting their weight:

Which should just return the product of 2,20462 * kg  of the corresponding European.

Because only Europeans need to be converted to pound, Im struggle to understand where to put the method(In Citizen or in European) `setWeight` and how.

I have tried to put setWeight in European like:

```
    public class European extends Citizen {

      public double weightconversion;

      public European(int weight) {
          super(weight);
      }
      @Override
      public double doubleValue() {
          return weight;
      }

      public void setWeight(double weightconversion)
      {
          this.weightconversion=weightconversion;
      }
      public double getWeight() {
          return weightconversion * weight;
      }

    }
```

But that seems not to be correct to use `European.setWeight(2,20462);`

Appreciate any insights!

Comment: `setWeight` takes one parameter. The value `2,20462` is seen as 2 parameters. If the comma is meant to be a decimal symbol, then use `2.20462`, instead.

Comment: It doesn't look like Peter, John and Francoise should be classes at all. Classes are blueprints for objects. Peter is not a type of Citizen, he is a Citizen. I think what you need is a `public class European extends Citizen` and a `public class American extends Citizen` and then each person will be an instance of those classes.

Comment: Good idea @mypetlion. Extending your idea, the weights would be handled per American (lbs) and European (kg). My idea was - add a `String` property called `units` to the class and store either `kg` or `lbs` and work with either accordingly in the getWeight function. Better yet, use an `Enum` to store string constants and prevent bugs.

Comment: hi @mypetlion thank you for you suggestion. but its just semantics. it does not help me to answer my question on how and where `setweight`

Comment: Not it's not semantics. I'm trying to indicate to you that there is no good place to put it until your class structure is cleaned up properly. `Françoise.setWeight(2,20462);` means that `setWeight` is a static method if `Françoise` is the name of your class. Static methods cannot be overridden and therefore defeats the purpose of using an abstract parent class.

Comment: @mypetlion anyways I updated my question since your suggestion does make more sense then my description

Comment: Note that decimal values in Java are **always** written with a **decimal point**, not comma. So `setWeight(2,20462)` should probably be `setWeight(2.20462)`. The comma would be interpreted as argument separation, by that you feed the `setWeight` method two arguments: `2` and `20462` instead of the `double` value `2.20462`.

Answer (score 2):

Lets start with the classes that extends `Citizen`. If you are working with european and american citizens, then you should create classes like this:

```
public class European extends Citizen { //code}
public class American extends Citizen { //code}
```

Then, you just instanciate those classes:

```
Citizen peter = new European(weight1);
Citizen francoise = new European(weight2);
Citizen john = new American(weight3);
```

Then, about your setWeight method. It should be declared as an abstract method in the `Citizen` class.

**Citizen class:**

```
public abstract void setWeight(int w);
```

Then you just implement that method in `American` an `European` classes. If only that method should be of the European class, then you can define it in the European class, but you should instanciate the object like this (in order not to get compilation error):

```
European peter = new European(weight1);
European francoise = new European(weight2);
```

Consider that what you want is just a conversion method. It could go also in an util class, and don´t mess the European class with a method that doesn´t fit.

In addition, you can assign the `2.20462` value in a variable of the European class. In that case, you don´t need any additional method. When you create an European, in the constructor you make that assigment.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. Given my example above I cant either use the method like `Peter.setWeight(0.01)` or instanciate `European Peter = new European();` since I have to pass parameters

Comment: @Googme Yes, in the constructor of `European` you should pass the weight of each. I updated my answer to be more clear. Also you should first create the objects (`Peter`, `Francoise`) and using that objects call the method `setWeitgh(number)`

Also, if that number you will pass to the method, is always 2.20462, why don´t you assing that number when calling the constructor?

Comment: Its not about how many possibilities they are to set weight. Its about how to `setWeitgh(number)` at the beginning, before instanciating an object as in my example above

Comment: @Googme >Its about how to setWeitgh(number) at the beginning, before instanciating an object 

You never told that before. Try to edit your first post, in order to be more clear of what you want.

Comment: Hmm the example is pretty self explanatory with code where `European.setWeight(2,20462); # should convert Françoise to pound` is used at the beginning. But anyway thx!

Comment: Please stick to naming conventions. Variable names, like method names, always start with **lowercase**, so it's `peter` not `Peter` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You could create:

```
public abstract class KgCitizen extends Citizen {
    public KgCitizen(double weight) {
        super(weight*2.2);
    }
}
```

and then have your Europeans extend that class.  (I hope my math is correct.)

By the way, if you do it this way, it would seem that Citizen should implement doubleValue() since all of your subclasses have the very same implementation.  You could still have Citizen be abstract, even though it has no abstract methods, in order to avoid anyone instantiating Citizen directly.

If you would rather have the weight that is stored in your objects be in the local area's unit of measure, rather than all pounds, but want doubleValue() to provide pounds only, then you could implement doubleValue() in KgCitizen to do the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Look at following structure and you will able to understand

```
public abstract class Citizen {

  public double weight;

  /**
   * Constructor of the abstract class
  */
  public Citizen(double weight) {
    this.weight = weight;
  }

  public abstract double convertWeight();

  public double doubleValue() {
    return convertWeight();
  } 
}
```

European

```
// Provide conversion logic for european in this class
public class European extends Citizen {

   public European(double weight) {
      super(weight);
   }

   @Override
   public double convertWeight() {
      return this.weight * 2;
   }

}
```

American

```
// Provide conversion logic for american in this class
public class American extends Citizen {

  public American(double weight) {
      super(weight);
  }

  @Override
  public double convertWeight() {
      return this.weight;
  }

}
```

John

```
public class John extends American {
  public John(int weight) {
    super(weight);
  } 
}
```

Peter

```
public class Peter extends European {
  public Peter(int weight) {
    super(weight);
  }
}
```

Francoise

```
public class Francoise extends European {
  public Francoise(int weight) {
      super(weight);
  }
}
```

Main

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String arp[]) {

      List<Citizen> weightiness = new ArrayList<Citizen>();
      weightiness.add(new John(90));
      weightiness.add(new Peter(90));
      weightiness.add(new Francoise(90));

      for (int i = 0; i < weightiness.size(); i++) {
          System.out.println(weightiness.get(i).doubleValue());
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Where do you define the method `setWeight` and invoke it?

Comment: It´s wrong to have `John`, `Peter`, and `Francoise` as classes.

Comment: @Googme There is no need of `setWeight ` method as we are passing it through constructor if you still want `setWeight ` method we can add  concrete method  `setWeight` in Citizen class

Comment: How are you going to do that in Citizen?

Comment: @SantiagoSalem Yes creating classes `Jhon`,`Peter` and `Francoise` not a good idea. But he is new and wants to understand use of abstract classes. So purpose is to understand abstract class functionality

Comment: @Googme just add `public void setWeight(int weight) { this.weight=weight}` in Citizen class and you will able to use it through out hierarchy

Comment: But I cant reference non-static method then: `Peter.setWeight(number)`; with `public void setWeight(int weight) { this.weight=weight}` can I?